# Select only part of combobox string or store two values per index possible?

Tags: c#

Here's what I have so far:

I have a ComboBox that I'm filling via pulling some playlists from a C# Spotify API.
I get the values - `playlist.Id` and `playlist.Name` from a playlist object.

Each playlist populates its Id and Name into a row in my ComboBox dropdown so the user can see a list of their personal playlists.

Next, the user chooses their selected playlist in the ComboBox and can pull a ListView of all the tracks (artists etc).

This step requires selecting the user's ComboBox selection but I can only use the `playlist.Id` value. However, I need to include the playlist.Name in the box so the user knows what playlist to select.

Obviously, this is pulling the name AND Id from the selected ComboBox option and I can't use these two values for the tracklist pull. I only want the Id string.

Is there any way to select only part of the ComboBox string (just the ID) or assign a value and a text separately to one row in my ComboBox?

Appreciate I'm probably doing this a silly way.

I've also tried:

Creating a separate array with just the playlist Id's and trying to use the selected index of ComboBox to match with the array index (only containing the id and not the name).

```
userPlaylists.Items.ForEach(playlist =>
{
    playlistArray[i] = playlist.Id;
    comboPlaylists.Items.Add(playlist.Name + playlist.Id);
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Yes, there is but it's not the right way. Instead of adding the names and IDs to the comboBox, set the `DataSource` property to the collection of PlayLists.

Comment: I did try this yesterday but my combobox was empty. Let me research it further. Thanks.

Comment: If you set the DataSource, you need to supply the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways to extract part of the ComboBox text but this isn't the right way. Instead, you should use [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-a-windows-forms-combobox-or-listbox-control-to-data). Set the `DataSource`, `DisplayMember`, and `ValueMember` properties of the ComboBox so that you can later access the `SelectedValue` which would be the ID.

Here's an example:

```
comboPlaylists.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboPlaylists.ValueMember = "Id";

// I'm assuming that `userPlaylists.Items` is a generic list. 
// Otherwise, you might want to use `userPlaylists.Items.ToList()` instead.
comboPlaylists.DataSource = userPlaylists.Items;
```

Now, when you want to get the Id of the selected PlayList, you can use something like this:

```
var id = (int)comboPlaylists.SelectedValue;  // Assuming the ID is an integer.
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Used the above userPlaylists.Items as datasource.